# How to search beginning of words with elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch

How to set up an elastic search that allows me to search part of words or beginning of words.

When I run the following script, it does not find the prefix 'inte' unless I make it 'inte*'.

I cannot figure out what is wrong here!

```
echo "--- DELETING OLD INDEX ---"

curl -XDELETE 'http://localhost:9200/searchtest?pretty'

echo "--- CREATING INDEX ---"

curl -XPUT 'http://127.0.0.1:9200/searchtest/?pretty=1' -d '{
   "mappings" : {
      "mytype" : {
         "properties" : {
           "description": {
              "type": "string",
              "index_analyzer": "my_analyzer",
              "search_analyzer": "standard"
            }
         }
      }
   },
   "settings" : {
      "analysis" : {
         "analyzer" : {
            "my_analyzer" : {
               "filter" : [ "standard", "lowercase", "stop" ],
               "type" : "custom",
               "tokenizer" : "my_tokenizer"
            }
         },
         "tokenizer" : {
            "my_tokenizer" : {
               "side" : "front",
               "max_gram" : 200,
               "type" : "edgeNGram"
            }
         }
      }
   }
}'

echo "--- INSERTING RECORDS ---"

curl -XPOST 'http://localhost:9200/searchtest/mytype?pretty=1' -d '{
  "description": "Programming International!"
}'

curl -XPOST 'http://localhost:9200/searchtest/mytype?pretty=1' -d '{
  "description": "i18n is internationalizatin"
}'

echo "--- REFRESH ---"

curl -XPOST 'http://localhost:9200/_refresh?pretty=1'

echo "--- RUNNING QUERY WITH * ---"

curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/searchtest/mytype/_search?pretty' -d '
{
   "query" : {
      "query_string" : {
         "query" : "inte*"
      }
   }
}'

echo "--- RUNNING QUERY ---"

curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/searchtest/mytype/_search?pretty' -d '
{
   "query" : {
      "query_string" : {
         "query" : "inte"
      }
   }
}'
```

[I am using elasticsearch 0.90.9]

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing wrong with that, the query_string use the the query parser which supports wildcards as you can see [here](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-query-string-query.html#_wildcards).

Maybe you are looking for a prefix query, which match terms starting with a given prefix, take a look to this [link](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-prefix-query.html)

```
curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/searchtest/mytype/_search?pretty' -d '
{
  "query" : {
    "prefix" : {
         "description" : {
            "value" : "inte"
        }
     }
  }
}'
```

Comment: More scalable than wildcard query suggested below.

Answer (score 0):

i think you are looking for wildcard query...

```
curl -XPOST "http://_search" -d'
{
"query": {
    "wildcard": {
       "description": {
          "value": "inte*"
                      }
                 }
         }
}'
```

try the above query for query with wildcard and also for regex..!

HOpe it helps..!